# SQL: In Oracle, how do you add a constraint so that the first character is a 0?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm creating a table which needs a column for phone numbers.

A restriction I have to make is that the first character has to be '0'.

How exactly can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

```
alter table YourTable 
  add constraint CHK_YourTable_PhoneNr check (PhoneNr like '0%')
```

Answer (score 1):

or even simpler:

```
create table tab_name(
   phone_nr type char(15) check ( phone_nr like '0%' )
);
```

Comment: I'd always supply a constraint name myself